# Need some WinForms and DataSet advice

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Here's the story: I've been working on putting together an app in VS10 using Windows Forms in C++. This is my first experience with winforms, although I have a fair amount of experience with C++ and have worked with MFC a bit. The program needs to aquire data input from a hardware measurement system and the backend for that is mostly worked out. What I've been a bit stuck on is how to easily work with displaying this data in forms with the `DataGridView` and `Char`t objects. I'd also like to be able to save various sets of data and the programs current settings to disk that can be easily recalled and displayed in the program at a later point.

The solution I've been attempting so far has been to create a `DataSet` object for a certain program instance which holds some `DataTable`s for the data and current settings. This is easily  saved and read to XML files using the DataSet methods, which is nice. The tricky part for me using this method has been trying to sync up the program's display data and settings in the `DataGridView`s and `Chart`s. It seems like these controls are really meant to be designed through the GUI. Maybe I'm just a noob, but I couldn't figure out how to get the `DataSet` I designed to link with my `Chart`s using the "Add Project data source" dialog, so instead I set up a `bindingSource` and then proceeded to set `Chart` settings manually in the code. That's been getting hairy pretty quickly.

What would you have done to implement this, and how would you advise proceeding? I'm sure there has to be a much simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422) to display data from hardware measurement systems before with good results.

We store our data separately in arrays and when we want to display something, just call the `AddXY` function on the items to add a point. Configuring the graph in the first place is more easily done in designer though. Have a look at [the samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418) for more info.